# Програмная смена языка на виртуально клавиатуре Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Есть WPF проект. Windows 10. При переходе на определённые View вызывается процесс `osk.exe` - экранная клавиатура.

Периодически нужно менять язык, но предполагается, что не все знают комбинацию клавиш для этого действия. Поэтому решено добавить кнопку, которая изменяет язык ввода на уровне ОС

```
      private void ChangeLang()
      {
         if (InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage.Name == "ru-RU")
         {
            InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            IsRussian = false;
            return;
         }

         InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
         IsRussian = true;
      }
```

Этот вариант работает, но есть недостаток - язык на экранной клавиатуре переключается не сразу, при этом, нужно немного передвинуть клавиатуру или как-то с ней повзаимодействовать.

Вопросы такие:

1) Можно ли как-то ускорить обновление раскладки на клавиатуре?

или

2) Сделать симуляцию нажатия `Shift + Alt`?

Если нажать на экранной клавиатуре `Shift` затем `Alt` затем снова `Shift`, то раскладка сменится быстро.

Comment: Послать какое-то сообщение окну клавиатуры?

Comment: @АндрейNOP а можно поподробнее, что вы имеете ввиду?)

Comment: Имею ввиду ф-и FindWindow и SendMessage в user32.dll

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вы имеете ввиду отправить пустое сообщение или сообщение, которое как-то переключить раскладку?

Comment: Либо сообщение для переключения раскладки, либо для *нужно немного передвинуть клавиатуру или как-то с ней повзаимодействовать*

Answer (score 0):

osk.exe не принимает команды вроде cmd => osk.exe /CHANGELANGUAGE
вот нашел другую клавиатуру которая принимает команды [посмотри тут](https://hot-virtual-keyboard.com/development/q8/)

Comment: Минус такой, что она распространяется по платной модели